# Setting up man-db crashes system with Bad system calls

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, manpage

Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64.
Ever since I upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04, whenever I install or run updates and the subsequent man-db update occurs, the system gets stuck for ten minutes or so spitting out errors and hitting the cpu hard.

```
Setting up man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Updating database of manual pages ...
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat: Bad system call (core dumped)
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/wodim.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
/usr/bin/mandb: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE -q: Bad system call (core dumped)
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/grub-editenv.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat: Bad system call (core dumped)
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/grub-editenv.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
/usr/bin/mandb: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE -q: Bad system call (core dumped)
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/grub-file.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
.
.
.
```

Furthermore, manpages throw errors and are empty:

```
     Manual page man(1) line ?/? (END) (press h for help or q to quit)man: 
    zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
    man: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv: Bad system call (core dumped)man: preconv: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    man: tbl: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    man: nroff: Bad system call (core dumped)
man: gzip: Bad system call (core dumped)
```

There's a bug report on Debian describing a similar issue, https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=890355, but I'm already running the version of `man-db` that supposedly fixed the problem (2.8.3). Tried reinstalling `man-db` to no effect. Did anybody experience anything similar, and how to fix?

Here is the link to the requested trace file:

[manpage.trace](https://ufile.io/507wb)

Comment: Hi.  man-db maintainer here.  Please could you run `sudo strace -f -o man.trace -s 1024 man man`, and attach the resulting man.trace file in an email to me (cjwatson@debian.org)?  I should be able to work it out from that.

Comment: Same problem here, output of above command: 
man: zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
man: nroff: Bad system call (core dumped)
 Manual page man(1) line ?/? (END) (press h for help or q to quit)man: /usr/lib/man-db/zsoelim: Bad system call (core dumped)
man: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv -f UTF-8:ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8//IGNORE: Bad system call (core dumped)

Comment: Manual page man(1) line ?/? (END) (press h for help or q to quit)zcat < /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz: Bad system call (core dumped)
man: nroff: Bad system call (core dumped)
man: /usr/lib/man-db/manconv: Bad system call (core dumped)
man: preconv: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
man: tbl: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
man: gzip: Bad system call (core dumped)

Comment: Please note that I am not interested in the *output* of that command, but only in the *resulting man.trace file*.

Comment: Sent an email with trace file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had several replies to my request for `strace` output, for which many thanks.  Most of them indicate use of the Astrill VPN software, which injects code into every process on the system using `/etc/ld.so.preload`, thus making effective process sandboxing quite a bit more difficult.  I believe I've [worked around this](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/commit/?id=5e08ee9a4e563abedbdd2768c8bbfd96b57c1859) in git master.

One reply indicated use of the ESET File Security antivirus software, which does a similar thing.  I've tried to work around problems with this in the past, but it seems to be a bit of a moving target.  I've committed my [best guess at a workaround](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/commit/?id=7582fb9d69a126a53ee11223b12346d38c0f333a) to git master.

Assuming that I get some successful test reports about these changes, they'll be in man-db 2.8.4, and they're small and self-contained enough that I should be able to push them as stable updates to Ubuntu 18.04 as well.

Comment: Thanks for ID'ing Astrill as the culprit. I didn't even realize it was still installed. I no longer use it, so apt-get remove astrill --purge fixed the problem.

Comment: I have installed fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, and I've noticed same issue with mandb - I also have Astrill installed but being expat in China I cannot work without VPN. I've checked and mandb version is 2.8.3. Do you know when will official 2.8.4 be available? Currently whenever I need to install anything, mandb starts outputting tons of "Bad system call" (installation of php7.2 was a nightmare) and overheats my laptop. If I leave it long enough, at the end installation goes through, but would be nice if it could be fixed. Looking forward for your feedback!

Comment: @Sinisa I released 2.8.4 on the same day that you posted that comment.  18.04 won't get 2.8.4 directly, but I've opened https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/man-db/+bug/1785414 to backport the sandbox fixes, and an upload for that is pending review.  The bug will be updated when it's available.

Comment: @ColinWatson I have enabled pre-released updates (bionic proposed) and after running the update (took quite some time), it seems that mandb issue disappeared. It's worth to note however that when I check mandb --version, I still get version 2.8.3, so mandb was not updated in latest pre-released items, and yet it does not cause (for now) anymore trouble. I've installed some software after this update, and mandb did not got stuck with "Bad system call". May be important info for you.

Comment: @Sinisa Good to know, thank you.  `mandb --version` isn't fine-grained enough for this - if you check `dpkg -l man-db`, you'll find that man-db was indeed updated to version 2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1, in which I included some backported fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem and seen it on a number of machines, I contacted Astrill and they wrote back:

"This is caused by apparmor. Make sure to update astrill to the latest version. I tried to improve this by excluding some programs which misbehave. Basically apparmor crashes those programs when they try to access shared memory instead of denying access by returning corresponding error core. I believe this is a bug in apparmor or system libaries and I can't do much about this except exclude such programs.

I made a configuration file where you can exclude misbehaving programs, by specifying executable name, one per line:
/etc/lsp.exclude

I fixed man in some recent versions so make sure you have the latest astrill version. If it's not working, try to figure out which programs to add to the list. Please send me the list back and I can then have this included in next version.

I have excluded sshd, bash, sh, grotty, groff, man"

I can confirm if mandb is added /etc/lsp.exclude the problem goes away (at least on my machine). I have also informed Astrill.

UPDATE: I've been informed by Astrill they will add mandb to /etc/lsp.exclude

UPDATE: I have forwarded your comments to astrill, I have been informed by them that the next update will exclude mandb but...

Comment: Your contact at Astrill is wrong: this is not caused by AppArmor, but rather by a strict seccomp sandbox in man-db that limits which system calls are used.  This is intentional and not in general a bug, although man-db 2.8.4 weakens the sandbox a little to cope with Astrill.  If you're in contact with Astrill, then please (pretty please!) ask them to change their preload library to only do the things it does when a process touches something to do with networking; there is no excuse for it mucking around with other processes.

Answer (score 0):

This `Bad system call` problem also occurs if you run an `apt-get` upgrade using the `nocache(1)` tool and it has to update some man pages:

```
# nocache apt-get --yes dist-upgrade
[...]
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.42) ...                          
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...                           
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man8/grub-bios-setup.8.gz: Bad system call
 (core dumped)                                                                  
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man8/grub-bios-setup.8.gz: Bad system call
 (core dumped)                                                                  
/usr/bin/mandb: zcat < /usr/share/man/man8/grub-install.8.gz: Bad system call (c
ore dumped)
[...etc...]
```

The man page for `nocache()` explains that it does use an added system call:

```
This is done by intercepting the `open` and `close` system calls and
calling `posix_fadvise` with the `POSIX_FADV_DONTNEED` parameter.
```

- Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- Linux xxx 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux