# Changing /bin/sh to zsh crashes man pages

Tags: 18.04, zsh, manpage

Just a general curiosity: 
Man pages on my Ubuntu 18.04.03 stop working when I change /bin/sh to zsh with following error:

```
man: nroff: Bad system call (core dumped)
```

What I did was:

```
rm -rf /bin/sh
ln -s /bin/zsh /bin/sh
```

However, the following with either bash or dash solved the problem:

```
rm -rf /bin/sh

ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
```

Kernel :

```
uname -r 
5.0.0-36-generic
```

manpages version;

```
man --version
man 2.8.3
```

Can someone please explain what is going on?

Comment: Possibly related: [Setting up man-db crashes system with Bad system calls](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039629/setting-up-man-db-crashes-system-with-bad-system-calls)

Comment: No really, I don't have either of those software and the problem seems to be related to zsh I guess.

Comment: You should NOT be altering the `/bin/sh` because that links somewhere else, and other things depend on `dash` and such that `sh` links to.  Are you simply trying to change your local user shell?

Comment: Actually, I was just trying to use my aliases in zshrc in jupyter notebook's shell command feature. But in the process broke man pages.

Comment: Don't replace `/bin/sh`. That is pretty much guaranteed to break things.

Comment: FYI this works fine on my 19.10; the issue is probably elsewhere...